# Websocket : Get information from Web socket server

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am very new to websockets and trying to create an omegle as an example. A centralized chat server to which every client can connect through a websocket and the the server matches people based on interests. The people can chat through the websocket connection thereafter.

I am just curious about one thing: Once my site goes live and different clients keep connecting, essentially in the background they are connecting to my central server through the websocket. Can't any client run javascript on its chrome console and inject a malicious script or get access to the clients connected to the server already since the connection has been established and its a stateful connection?  I am not sure if there is a way to do that. And if there is, what security mechanisms i need to take care of?

Comment: All you need to understand about the websocket protocol!

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Please, check if your answer is there.

Comment: Inject a script into what? Any information sharing between clients only happens through the server. You are in control of that server. What do you mean by "get access to the clients connected to the server"?

Comment: What backend are you using? Java? NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is "Yes" and "No"!

it depends on so many things. First, is your chat a public one? I mean can every body join the chat room without login?

In this case i guess everybody can chat so a guy who want to use your websockets can do so a it is public.

In the case your chat is private it is your own to protect your websockets events from being accessed by everybody. This start by registering users after a robust login process.

As all others Internet (and computer based) tech, websocket is subject to hacking. You chould protect your websockets as you protect your web based developments.

Typing "websocket common attacks" in Google will return you links that talk of websocket security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a client can definitely inject a malicious script... *but it will only affect the client's own browser.*

No. There isn't a way to do that unless you explicitly created a vulnerability.

You see, first of all, websockets are not peer-to-peer connections. They require a server to transmit messages between end users, so if the server doesn't do anything about an incoming message request, the user the first user intended to send a message to would not receive anything. Essentially, this means that websocket clients can only connect to users if the server lets them.

However, *even if* websockets were p2p connections that would *still not be possible*, or what kind of a web would we have?! I hope you understand that any data sent to a client isn't automatically executed as code. It usually is in a string format and it will never be able to run any code unless you actually `eval` it or something. (Or you forget about XSS and don't properly escape data that would be rendered as HTML.)

So, to answer your question, no and no. Security measures? Don't `eval` incoming data.

However, what you *do* have to be aware of in websockets is that any client can connect (well, at least try) to a websocket server. See, because websockets usually are used to send data *between* clients, when a server receives a message, it usually will broadcast that message to *everyone* in that connection/room except for the sender. This means that a user with malicious intent may enter your room and send data, as well as receive data that's probably meant to be private.
To prevent this, ensure you are setting up proper authentication. You can do this through cookies, perhaps, used with session or JWT (I usually use the latter). When a user joins a room or connects, check if that user is authorized and allowed to be in the room. Otherwise, reject the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit broader explanation that might help you.

Web sockets work on TCP connections. That means the socket connects to a specific destination and transmits data ("messages"). Those messages can flow both ways (in and out). Users connect to your server using clients (most commonly a browser).

The connections are unique, meaning no two clients share the same connection. Therefore, no one else knows what others send to or receive from the server.

Messages can be of various types, but the most commonly used is a string. Typically people encode some JSON objects in those strings to perform specific actions. Something along the lines of:

```json
{
   message: "Hello!",
   channel: "general"
}
```

Now here comes your role. How to act on those messages, and what to send to whom. Standard libraries provide functionalities like targeting a single socket or sending messages to many sockets. Imagine it like a list of connections. They can send specific commands to join/leave channels, so you add more meta data to each. In the previous example, you might want to send `Hello!` to every connection that has "joined" a channel (by sending a specific command to do so).

You decide what the commands are:

```json
{
   command: "join/leave",
   channel: "general"
}
```

You might want to spread every message you receive to others or keep it to yourself (and execute some custom functionality). Nothing happens out of the box - the server receives the message, and that's it.

---

All of the above means that whatever users do with their clients won't affect you or others. The only way you can know of their actions is if they send you a message. Those messages you **must** be careful with, as they can contain any malicious code.

Therefore I'd highly recommend you use some library that deals with web sockets in case you'd like to ship something to people. If it's for learning purposes - stick to the plain functionalities.